# Flutter flavor does not refer the resource folder

Tags: flutter, push-notification, android-resources, android-push-notification, android-flavors

I have arranged my app flavor folders and the `build.gradle` file specification as below image.

[image: Code implementation]

Resource files are identical in both flavors but image content are different (ex: red color and green color). Flavor1 works fine in every aspect, but the flavor2 partially does not get the relevant resource folder given for the flavor.

Flavor2 takes the app icon and app name correctly from resources, but only the local **push notification icon** is not taking and showing a dot instead.

I have removed the resource folder in `main` folder in order to force to take the flavor wise resource folder, but no luck.

I have tried many ways to fix this but still not a success.
**Any idea would be helpful. TIA**